# How to create a class in Javacscript from a class in C# in VS2008 

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2008

How do I create a class in Javacscript from a class in C#?

Comment: In it's current form, not a real question imo (voting to close). Please edit your question to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp).

Answer (score 0):

```
    try this one...

class UserCreator {
    constructor(name, family, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.family = family;
        this.email = email;
    }
    loggin() {
        console.log(this.email + " logged in");
        return this;
    }
    loggout() {
        console.log(this.email + " logged out");
        return this;
    }
}

class Admin extends UserCreator {
    deleteUser() {
        users = users.filter()
    }
}

var userOne = new UserCreator("Max", "Green", "max@yahoo.com");
var userTwo = new UserCreator("Lili", "Bell", "lili@gmail.com");
var users = [userOne, userTwo];
userOne.loggin().loggout();
userTwo.loggout();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34111176)